# In Grafana, is there a way to re-use parts of Prometheus queries with templated parameters?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql, grafana-templating

I find myself repeating very similar Prometheus queries in Grafana, with minor differences (mostly to the metric name). Is there a way to reuse these and supply the metric name as a parameter?

As an example, I have the following query:

```
label_replace(erlang_vm_ets_limit{instance=~"[^.]*${host}.*",env="${env}",app="${app}"}, "host", "$1", "instance", "[^.]*?(\\d+).*")
```

Now I want the same query for the metric `erlang_vm_memory_ets_tables` (and many others). I'd love to be able to store the query somewhere with a parametrizable metric name, e.g. `label_replace([[metric_name]]{instance=~"[^.]*${host}.*",env="${env}",app="${app}"}, "host", "$1", "instance", "[^.]*?(\\d+).*")`. Is something like that possible? Or is there another Grafana-native way to re-use parts of Prometheus queries?

Comment: Do you need it to be used in different panels or within the same one?

Comment: @markalex Across different panels, and preferably across different dashboards as well.

Answer (score 1):

The best idea in this case would be to add [relabeling config](https://%20https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config) like

```yaml
- source_labels: [instance]
  regex: "[^.]*?(\\d+).*"
  target_label: "host"
  replacement: "$1"
```

It will automatically add label `host` to every metric based on regex.

---

If relabeling at the scrape time is not possible, only way to reuse parts of queries is to create a couple of dashboard variable of type **Constant**:

- `q_prefix` with value `label_replace(`,
- `q_postfix` with value `, "host", "$1", "instance", "[^.]*?(\\d+).*")`

And use query like

```
${q_prefix}erlang_vm_ets_limit{instance=~"[^.]*${host}.*",env="${env}",app="${app}"}${q_postfix}
```

Grafana will simply constitute them before sending query to Prometheus.

Sadly the is not simple way to make selectors part of this variables: Grafana doesn't support defining variable based on value of another variable.

Also, since those are dashboard variables, this will work only within single dashboard, and it will be needed to repeat for every dashboard.

---

One more alternative, is to create own plugin, that will provide substitution of the format you'll define, but I doubt this would be a reasonable choice in most (if any) cases.